# How to set the value for form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want save multiple individual records for a single model. So my form will have `<input>` elements with IDs that look like this `Author0Title`; `Author1Title`; `Author2Title`, etc.

I will be getting values for these input's using `jQuery.getJSON()` method.

I want to assign individual values for these input like these automatically.

```
document.getElementById('Author0Title').value = respose.data[0].title;
```

something like..

```
for(i=0;i<response.data.length; i++){
    var id = 'Author' + i + 'Title';
    document.getElementById(id).value = respose.data[0].title;
}
```

But it is not working. I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: would you mind post here entire code section, which deals with it?

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
  $('#Author' + i + 'Title').val(response.data[i].title);
}
```

That's pretty close to your example, except that you've got '0' coded in as the index instead of 'i'.

Make sure that your `<input>` elements really are using both an "id" and a "name" that's constructed as you expect. If they're just getting the "name" attribute set, you could do this:

```
  $('input[name=Author' + i + 'Title]').val(response.data[i].title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're misspelling respose -> response?

Otherwise, "should work". Assuming your JSON actually matches what you're looking for in this code.

Since you're using jQuery, you might want to use `$('#Author' + i + 'Title').val(response.data[i].title);` instead - although it does the same.